# invalid path while trying to write the file in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

i am trying to write to a text file in oracle pl sql(10 g).
i have created the directory it is existing but still getting invalid path.
below is the code.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'c:\';
-- CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS '/tmp';

DECLARE
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('test_dir', 'test_file.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, 'Writing TO a file\n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_file.invalid_path THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.');
END;
/

the following is the error:
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Comment: Is the database running on the same PC as the directory? A common mistake is to try to get utl_file on a remote database server to read a file on your local desktop.

Comment: yes robert i am trying this script on my desktop

Comment: OK, but is the database actually running on your desktop PC, or is it on a separate database server somewhere?

Comment: database is running on my pc

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is case sensitive. But all names in SQL and PL/SQL are automatically converted to uppercase unless enclosed in double quotes.

So:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'c:\';
```

is actually executed as:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS 'c:\';
```

Therefore the directory you have defined is called `TEST_DIR`. If you refer to it in a string (as opposed to a symbol name in SQL or PL/SQL), you must use `'TEST_DIR'`. `'test_dir'` won't work.

Thus try:

```
fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TEST_DIR', 'test_file.txt', 'W');
```