# Invalid PATH for file

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I am testing the following code in TOAD.

---

```
create directory test_dir AS 'c:\';
DECLARE
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('test_dir', 'test_file.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, 'Test writing to a file.\n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_file.invalid_path THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.');
END;
```

---

It returns the following error:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-20000: ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this error? Thanks so much!

Comment: Change `'test_dir'` to `'TEST_DIR'`. See duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873133/invalid-path-while-trying-to-write-the-file-in-pl-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid path while trying to write the file in pl sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873133/invalid-path-while-trying-to-write-the-file-in-pl-sql)

Comment: Tried 'TEST_DIR' but it still didn't work. Could the error be caused by the fact that the database is on a separate server?

Comment: Yes - UTL_FILE reads/writes files on the database server. If you want to write to a file on your client computer, it depends on your SQL client - SQL*Plus uses SPOOL, others have wizards to save different kinds of files.